# Windows 8 App w/ jQuery remove method

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8.1

I have been trying to create a windows 8 app using jQuery, but I have run into an issue with the security model. I need to remove some DOM elements, but I'm not sure how. At first, this is how I removed them, which doesn't work:

```
$("a").remove();
```

After that, I searched around the web for a while, then found this:

```
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () {
        $("a").remove();
});
```

For some reason, that didn't work either.

Does somebody know how to remove DOM elements in a windows 8 app, using jQuery or not?

Comment: How does it not work? It gets ignored? It triggers an error message? It removes the wrong stuff?

Comment: @idtownie Take a look here: [Wrapping the MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=3212). Is this how you try to use it?

Comment: @j809 Yes. I tried using the code on that site just now, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Nothing is logged to the console, so I'm not sure. It doesn't remove any elements.